# RxJS How to avoid Race operator to cancel "loser" HTTP Request Observable?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to create a race condition with RxJS where I have to query 2 API, but I only want to load a spinner if the data takes more than 150ms to arrive.

So the flow on the UI is: wait for 150ms - if data arrives display immediately, if it doesn't, load a spinner for at least ~250ms.

The logic works fine and the UI behaviour is correct.
The issue that I am having is that one API request might come back before 150ms, and one after, in which case I end up with the `race` operator cancelling the HTTP Request, and restarting it again after loading.

Is there a way to let the HTTP requests continue, even if they loose the race condition, so that I can replay them with `shareReplay` so that I never have to fire more than one HTTP call for each endpoint?

[image]

```
class GameDetailsService {
// more methods and fields are hidden as not relevant to this example.

  private state = initialState;

  private store = new BehaviorSubject<GameDetailsState>(this.state);
  private store$ = this.store.asObservable();
  selectedGame$ = this.store$.pipe(
    map((state) => state.selectedGameId),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((id): Observable<null | Game> => {
      if (id == null) {
        return this.clearGame();
      } else {
        return this.findGameDetails(id);
      }
    })
  );

private findGameDetails(id: string): Observable<Game> {
    const gameDetails$ = this.findGameById(id).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return of(null);
      }),
      retry(2)
    );
    const screenshots$ = this.findScreenshotsById(id).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return of(null);
      }),
      retry(2)
    );

    const data$ = forkJoin([gameDetails$, screenshots$]).pipe(
      filter(
        (data): data is [Game, { image: string }[]] =>
          data[0] != null && data[1] != null
      ),
      map(([gameDetails, screenshots]) => {
        // enhance game object with screenshots
        gameDetails.screenshots = screenshots;

        return gameDetails;
      }),
      tap((gameDetails) => {
        // create new state
        const newState = produce(this.state, (draft) => {
          draft.selectedGame = gameDetails;
          draft.loading = false;
        });
        this.state = newState;
        this.store.next(newState);
      }),
      shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
    );

    /**
     * We want to display the loading indicator only if the requests takes more than `${INITIAL_WAITING_TIME}
     * if it does, we want to wait at least `${MINIMUM_TIME_TO_DISPLAY_LOADER} before emitting
     */

    const startLoading$ = of({}).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('start loading ' + new Date().getSeconds())),
      tap(() => this.startLoadingGame()),
      delay(MINIMUM_TIME_TO_DISPLAY_LOADER),
      tap(() => console.log('emit finish loading ' + new Date().getSeconds())),
      switchMap(() => EMPTY)
    );

    const hideLoading$ = of({}).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('stop loading ' + new Date().getSeconds())),
      tap(() => this.stopLoadingGame()),
      switchMap(() => EMPTY)
    );

    const timer$ = timer(INITIAL_WAITING_TIME).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('timer emitted ' + new Date().getSeconds()))
    );

    /**
     * We want to race two streams:
     *
     * - initial waiting time: the time we want to hold on any UI updates
     * to wait for the API to get back to us
     *
     * - data: the response from the API.
     *
     * Scenario A: API comes back before the initial waiting time
     *
     * We avoid displaying the loading spinner altogether, and instead we directly update
     * the state with the new data.
     *
     * Scenario B: API doesn't come back before initial waiting time.
     *
     * We want to display the loading spinner, and to avoid awkward flash (for example the response comes back 10ms after the initial waiting time) we extend the delay to 250ms
     * to give the user the time to understand the actions happening on the screen.
     */

     const race$ = race(timer$, data$).pipe(
      mergeMap((winner) => (typeof winner === 'number' ? startLoading$ : EMPTY))
    );

    return concat(race$, hideLoading$, data$);
  }

  private findGameById(id: string): Observable<Game> {
    return this.http.get<Game>(`${env.BASE_URL}/games/${id}`);
  }

  private findScreenshotsById(id: string): Observable<{ image: string }[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<APIResponse<{ image: string }>>(
        `${env.BASE_URL}/games/${id}/screenshots`
      )
      .pipe(map(({ results: screenshots }) => screenshots));
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can answer my own question.

I was able to obtain the intended behaviour by modifying the `shareReplay` configuration.

Replacing:

```
shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
```

with

```
shareReplay(1) // shorthand for shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: false})
```

Reading the docs about [Reference Count](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay#reference-counting)

> By default shareReplay will use refCount of false, meaning that it will not unsubscribe the source when the reference counter drops to zero, i.e. the inner ReplaySubject will not be unsubscribed (and potentially run for ever). This is the default as it is expected that shareReplay is often used to keep around expensive to setup observables which we want to keep running instead of having to do the expensive setup again.

Which I believe makes sense, as we never want to "unsubscribe" in between the times we restore the `data$` and keep the value of the HTTP Response alive until the `concat([race$, hideLoading, data$])` resubscribes to it.

[image]

Even though the second requests takes >200ms, we never cancel and are able to resume and display the data once the time delay has completed.